# What are the yellow bars on map locations in The Division?

Tags: the-division

Do the yellow bars on the top/bottom/left/right of map points of interest signify anything?  I've noticed 0, 1 and 2 bars.
As seen in the highlighted encounter (blue triangle) shown in the screenshot below, as well as the Phone Recording to the right.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure off hand but have you cross checked the legend? (Far left sub menu? L1 bumper it appears)?  If you have and it's not listed, may I suggest you simply note that?

Comment: Good point, but the legend does not define the meaning.

Comment: It seems to be an marker only appearing on newly discovered POIs highlighting them. But I don't got the point of why there are 1 or 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be markers to that show up opposite the POI from the center of your screen (at least on the PC version.)

I took a short video of it, here, that you can see.  Watch as I move the map around, the dots move around, so that they are always on the opposite side of the POI from the center of my screen.  They don't appear to serve any purpose other than decorative.

Comment: Well that's weird.

Comment: Agreed. It seems an odd decoration.

Comment: Good grief.  You're right.  The kicker is: as I move the cursor around a POI it changes from 1 to two to show a diagonal.  Good observation!  I was hoping it was something more interesting, like # of operatives in the area, but...

Answer (score 1):

Tldr :Those are markers to help you navigate. Use the corresponding arrow keys (bar on right = right arrow, etc.) to select that icon.
Info :
You will probably encounter icons that you can't reach using the mouse from time to time. It can be frustrating if you want to fast travel to them. Fortunately, using the arrows keys, you can select and navigate through those icons. Those markers indicate which icon you will select using the corresponding arrow key.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Not on PC so I can't really test it. Maybe the D-Pad will work.

Comment: I've actually tested this (prior to making that video) and it is not true.  I frequently had locations that had arrows on them that did not go anywhere, due to them being just decorations.