# What's the meaning of these icons in The Division?

Tags: the-division

What is the meaning of these orange rectangles on the map?
[image: screenshot showing the orange rectangles in question]

When I meet another player in the open world I see this number on him/her. I also have this symbol and number shown in my character selection, what is the meaning?
[image: screenshot showing another player's number]
[image: screenshot showing the number in my character selection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: The Division: screenshot showing three mission markers paired with small orange rectangles]

**These orange rectangles are markers**. 

They are always on the icon's side that's opposite of the player's location, and on the (up to) four icons of points of interest closest to the player.

**You can select, or switch, those nodes by pressing the corresponding keys** (<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, and <kbd>→</kbd>, for the ones in this particular image).

See also this picture:

[image: The Division: screenshot of map, showing four icons with the rectangles, and the corresponding usage in the legend]

---

[image: The Division: screenshot showing an orange icon (a dot between two bent brackets) and a score]

This symbol and its number indicate the **commendation level** of a player. 

This level can be increased by receiving [commendations](https://thedivision.fandom.com/wiki/Commendations). [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/88und6/the_all_in_one_commendation_cheesebest_way_to/) is a good overview of how to get some of them.

<sup>Sources:

https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/4b6xwh/what_do_the_little_orange_bars_by_some_of_the/

https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/8wlqgk/what_is_the_orange_symbol_and_numbers_next_to/

NB the first question actually already got an answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260137/what-are-the-yellow-bars-on-map-locations-in-the-division)</sup>